# SQL query with some conditions is working slow - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my issue, I have a table with `1,230,000` records and I'm doing this query in my app

```
SELECT id_product 
  FROM products 
 WHERE user_id = '322' 
   AND (status = 1 OR status = 3) 
   AND product_date BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-12-31' 
   AND required = 0
```

And this query get 206 records from the table (this is correct) but it takes like 4.5 seconds which is too much because I make this query multiple times with different values sometimes in the same page.

But if I do only this

```
SELECT id_product FROM products WHERE user_id = '322'
```

it takes 0.322 seconds

Every column in the WHERE statement has an index, so this is my question, is really necessary add conditions in the query? because in this case I dont see the point, I mean the first query find only what I need but it takes long time and the second query gets all but I could make the filter with the programming language I'm using or do you think there is something I'm missiing? I hope you can guide me, thanks.

Comment: Please add the output of `explain select ...` to your question.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you change the date check to use explicit `CAST (yourdate as DATE)`?

Comment: @juergend id = 1
select_type = SIMPLE
table = products
type = index_merge
possible_keys = idx_status,idx_id,idx_date,idx_required
key = idx_status,idx_id,idx_required
key_len = 4,4,4
ref = NULL
rows = 206
Extra = Using intersect(idx_id,idx_status,idx_required); Using where

Comment: That is what it displayed

Comment: What happens if you skip the `OR` and select only `status = 1`.. or perhaps like this `status in (1, 3)`. `OR` statements can sometimes slow down queries.

Comment: Please add the complete table structure and explain in actual post. Use UNION instead of OR operator to make it use the available indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation to use index hints to force your query to use or not to use the index like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 USE INDEX (col1_index,col2_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;

SELECT * FROM table1 IGNORE INDEX (col3_index)
  WHERE col1=1 AND col2=2 AND col3=3;
```

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Also, you might create a more efficient index including the other fields of your  WHERE if this is really necessary. Test both options and see what is better.

Comment: I tried this but it gave me error like the syntax is not correct.

Comment: Forcing index is not advisable.

Comment: Why not? Could you complement more your comment @money?

Comment: Using FORCE INDEX() indiscriminately can also easily backfire. The distribution of the data or the values of query parameters can change, and the key that you thought was best for the query can, over time, become a less preferred plan. FORCE KEY should be used when you understand exactly why you are using it, and are 100% sure that there is no way the key that is being forced could become bad.

Comment: Well, in a way that MySQL is not finding the best way to use the index and you know that it is doing this, sure in the future it might turn in backfire. Understood you point and was what I was thinking. Thanks.